# google map inflate exception on Android 8.0

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-2, android-8.0-oreo

We are developing an app that uses the google map sdk. the only problem is that the app crashes on android 8 and above. all other versions doesn't has any problem.

After passing intro activity and getting permissions, on Main Activity onCreate in set content view it appears.

The logcat error messages are:

```
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawableForDensity(TypedArray.java:953)
  at android.graphics.drawable.AdaptiveIconDrawable.updateLayerFromTypedArray(AdaptiveIconDrawable.java:516)
  at android.graphics.drawable.AdaptiveIconDrawable.inflateLayers(AdaptiveIconDrawable.java:480)
  at android.graphics.drawable.AdaptiveIconDrawable.inflate(AdaptiveIconDrawable.java:229)
  at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:142)
  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1295)
  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlForDensity(Drawable.java:1254)
  at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:791)
  at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:621)
  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:886)
  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawableForDensity(TypedArray.java:953)
  at android.graphics.drawable.AdaptiveIconDrawable.updateLayerFromTypedArray(AdaptiveIconDrawable.java:516)
  at android.graphics.drawable.AdaptiveIconDrawable.inflateLayers(AdaptiveIconDrawable.java:480)
  at android.graphics.drawable.AdaptiveIconDrawable.inflate(AdaptiveIconDrawable.java:229)
  at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:142)
  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1295)
  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlForDensity(Drawable.java:1254)
  at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:791)
  at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:621)
  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:886)
  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawableForDensity(TypedArray.java:953)
  at android.graphics.drawable.AdaptiveIconDrawable.updateLayerFromTypedArray(AdaptiveIconDrawable.java:516)
  at android.graphics.drawable.AdaptiveIconDrawable.inflateLayers(AdaptiveIconDrawable.java:480)
  at android.graphics.drawable.AdaptiveIconDrawable.inflate(AdaptiveIconDrawable.java:229)
  at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:142)
  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1295)
  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlForDensity(Drawable.java:1254)
  at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:791)
  at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:621)
  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:886)
  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawableForDensity(TypedArray.java:953)
  at android.graphics.drawable.AdaptiveIconDrawable.updateLayerFromTypedArray(AdaptiveIconDrawable.java:516)
  at android.graphics.drawable.AdaptiveIconDrawable.inflateLayers(AdaptiveIconDrawable.java:480)
  at android.graphics.drawable.AdaptiveIconDrawable.inflate(AdaptiveIconDrawable.java:229)
  at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:142)
  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1295)
  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlForDensity(Drawable.java:1254)
  at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:791)
  at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:621)
  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:886)
  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawableForDensity(TypedArray.java:953)
  at android.graphics.drawable.AdaptiveIconDrawable.updateLayerFromTypedArray(AdaptiveIconDrawable.java:516)
  at android.graphics.drawable.AdaptiveIconDrawable.inflateLayers(AdaptiveIconDrawable.java:480)
  at android.graphics.drawable.AdaptiveIconDrawable.inflate(AdaptiveIconDrawable.java:229)
  at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:142)
```

Comment: share caused by error from log cat

Comment: i sent in question the only android studio error log . what do you mean ?

Comment: search caused by in android error log cat and then share it

Comment: i don't understand what you mean . can you tell me more ?

Comment: guessing from the log your error is probably generating from a drawable source.

Comment: you should elaborate your question more precisely. What is the scenario that causes the error log ? seems to be a vector drawable or adaptive icon error.

Comment: i updated , you can see

Answer (score 1):

Please Check the Any DPI in the App resouce Folder. You must handle it.